# Macrorecorder RemoteKeys in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, wine

At work I use Windows7 and a very useful program called RemoteKeys. It's a macro manager like Actionaz. It can send complex keystrokes to another application using mouse clicks. 
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/RemoteKeys.shtml

I use it every day. You can make as many buttons to click as you want. It has several profiles. One of them is a keyboard. (Use Page Up to find the profile once the program is started.) If you click on a letter it should send the keystroke to for instance gedit (as active window).

In Ubuntu 14.04 (at home) I can start the program using wine, but nothing happens.

I was wondering if there was a way to make it run under Ubuntu or explain why it can't work.

Comment: This might be a possible solution: http://xnee.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

Wine is not an emulator. And RemoteKeys is pretty old software that works by manipulating the Windows API and inserting itself in-between the application layer and the API using **un**documented Windows calls.

As Wine just emulates the *documented* Windows API, this kind of software doesn't work and will not ever work (even when you would file a bug report).

You would get the same kind of behaviour if you would try to install Norton Anti-virus from 15 years ago: It just wouldn't work...  ;-)